How can phantom send the total amount of sol to an account and I get "Transaction would result in an account with insufficient funds for rent"
My question is: when I try to send the total amount of my solana balance from one account to another programatically (JS) I get an error saying that Transaction would result in an account with insufficient funds for rent (tx example: https://solscan.io/tx/2xfuWbDFKnj2RskQHVGWAdfbNw1xsyF46yZnZtS8PAEASKtXa27PMKYb2T8NwaDgJ6GQvHtzyou4hywrnySwoTxz)
But when I do the exact same thing through phantom, the transaction goes through and successfully transfers 100% of the funds to the other account.
I am using the same priority fees as phantom uses but that doesn't seem to be the problem.
The 2 transactions look identical, but mine doesn't go through while phantom's does.
Any ideas on why this might be happening? Thanks in advance!
the code Im using for creating the transaction is this:
    SystemProgram.transfer({
      fromPubkey: sourceKeypair.publicKey,
      toPubkey: destinationPubkey,
      lamports: balance-5000,
    })
  );


It look like there is a minimal balance which should remain for the account. You can check it via getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption method.

I'm not sure your tx fees are rights in your script, check https://solscan.io/tx/2xfuWbDFKnj2RskQHVGWAdfbNw1xsyF46yZnZtS8PAEASKtXa27PMKYb2T8NwaDgJ6GQvHtzyou4hywrnySwoTxz#solBalanceChange
It looks like it's 15000 lamports, not 5000

Some troubleshooting ideas

Make sure you are on the correct cluster. You might be trying to transfer your mainnet lamports on the devnet cluster but don't have an account on it.

Try fetching the balance programmatically instead of hardcoding it


// check the cluster here
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed");

// fetch account balance
let wallet = new PublicKey(" "); // update with your account address
await connection.getBalance(wallet);

